# Vimdiff strangeness

Tags: git, vim, macvim, vimdiff

I have strange problems with vimdiff, everytime I do something like this:

```
git difftool HEAD~2 -- src/some-file.hs
```

- first of all - it opens two separate windows, one - with the diff and the second - with the file by itself. Why and how do I fix that? I don't need no second window
- another problem is - it never makes width of two buffers same, the divider pushed all the way to the right and I have to manually do `C-w`+`=` to make them same width, how do I fix that?

difftooll set in `.gitconfig` as:

```
[diff]
    tool = gvimdiff
```

Also I have no idea how to set it right in SourceTree. I want to use vimdiff as external differ/merger

Answer (score 1):

You can use vim as a git merge-tool, but its default appearance is pretty messy as you've noticed. You can clean this up by wrapping vim in a custom script and using that instead - an example is here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool.

However if all you want is to view the diff directly and edit that, just open the file normally i.e. `vim src/some-file.hs`. git will have replaced the file with its version with conflict markers. YOu can use something like this to find the conflicts quickly `https://github.com/rhysd/conflict-marker.vim` - but I find just typing `\>>>>` is fast enough. For more complex cases I use the fugitive vim plugin (see next paragraph)

If you actually want to use vim to work on git conflicts on single files I'd recommend installing [fugitive.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) Then you can do.

```
:e src/some-file.hs
:Gdiff
```

And get three buffers with the original, left and right version. But `:Gdiff` also accepts version arguments so you can compare non-conflicting files too.